# How to filter ads programatically in android

Tags: android, mobile, ads

I have searched some solutions to android advertisement like AdMob, airpush or Google Ads. My question is: is there a way to filter ads dynamically?

Let's say somehow I know user A from my app likes sports, user B like movies, therefore, I would advertise sport stuff to user A and movie stuff to user B. Is there a way to filter ads that way as an android developer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ad systems already have these algorithms and will send you ad they think are relevent to your user.

Comment: As @litelite said, Ad systems have these algorithms but if you want the filter it again on your side, you can fetch the ads and apply your filters on it, If it doesn't match your criteria, just ignore that ad and fetch next one!

Comment: Thank you :) Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote you guys